# Serialization and inheritance

Tags: java

The answer to the following question (Sierra Bates SCJP guide) is **pcp**:

```
import java.io.*;

class Player {
    Player() { System.out.print("p"); }
}

class CardPlayer extends Player implements Serializable {
    CardPlayer() { System.out.print("c"); }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CardPlayer c1 = new CardPlayer();

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("play.txt");
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            os.writeObject(c1);
            os.close();

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("play.txt");
            ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            CardPlayer c2 = (CardPlayer) is.readObject();
            is.close();
        } catch (Exception x ) { }
    }
}
```

So it gets pcp thus:

> "pc" is printed as the serialized state of Cardplayer - the inherited p and Cardplayer's c. The third p in the output is the result of the superclass Player constructor running - as it's not serializable - printing p.

This is how the answer's derived is it not ?

Comment: Yes. What's your exact question?

Comment: You may find it easier if you think about what would happen if you had used delegation instead of inheritance.

Comment: Constructor of parent will get invoked and it will print `P` because your parent is not serializable.

Answer (score 2):

Answer is Yes.

[Java doc of Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)

> To allow subtypes of non-serializable classes to be serialized, the subtype may assume responsibility for saving and restoring the state of the supertype's public, protected, and (if accessible) package fields. The subtype may assume this responsibility only if the class it extends has an accessible **no-arg constructor to initialize the class's state**. It is an error to declare a class Serializable if this is not the case. The error will be detected at runtime

Comment: Ok, thanks everyone. Just needed to get verification on this question. That's all. I would have Neil but these are the type of questions likely to come up in the SCJP exam unfortunately.